# How to release and dispose all Http-scoped objects on Container instance?

Tags: c#, structuremap, httpcontext

In StructureMap, how can I release and dispose al Http-scoped objects on a specific Container instance? For the default intance in Object Factory, I can execute the method `ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects()`, but the Container class and the IContainer interface doesn't seem to have such method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the internals of `ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects`, you can see that it is a conveniency method implemented like this:

```
public static void ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects()
{
    HttpContextLifecycle.DisposeAndClearAll();
}
```

IE. You can invoke the `HttpContextLifecycle.DisposeAndClearAll` method to clear the objects.

Edit: Since the HttpContextLifecycle is global and not per container, I think that a [nested container](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2010/02/10/nested-containers-in-structuremap-2-6-1/) approach would be the solution to gain more fine grained control over the object lifetime during a Http Request.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to dispose all the Http scoped objects, not only those from the current container instance.

Comment: @guillegr123 - The `HttpContextLifecycle` is global, not per container.

Comment: If you want to control lifetime of specific objects within a `HttpRequest`, I think you should go with a [nested container](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2010/02/10/nested-containers-in-structuremap-2-6-1/) approach.

Comment: You are right @PHeiberg, it seems to be the best approach available at this time. Thank you very much.